# How to create a reuseable protected route in Next.js

Tags: authentication, next.js, supabase

I'm new to Next.js. I'm presently using Supabase magic links for auth. Based on this [awesome tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXWImFqsQF4), I made one of the pages on my app a protected route. I did this by adding the following code to the page file:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
    const { user } = await supabase.auth.api.getUserByCookie(req)
    if (!user) {
        return { props: {}, redirect: { destination: '/signin' } }
    }
    return { props: {user} }
}
```

It works well. However, I would need to copy paste this to any other page that I want to be a protected route. Is there a way to make this DRY so that can I make *specific* pages protected routes without copying this code every time?

I tried making a ProtectedRoute component with this code snippet. However, since it's a component and not a page, getServerSideProps never gets called. Is there an idiomatic way to do this in Next.js?

Answer (score 2):

You can use next.js middleware. More info: https://engineering.udacity.com/protected-routes-using-next-js-edge-middleware-supabase-f197ba7f503c

```js
// src/middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const middleware = async (request: NextRequest) => {
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard')) {
    const authCookie = request.cookies.get('supabase-auth-token');
    if (!authCookie) return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url));
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you @aanes1. In the time since I posted this I have dropped the Supabase magic links and now use NextAuth. I'm presently using `unstable_getServerSession` in the `getServerSideProps` of each page that is protected. This is not very DRY. I think I will try your solution and simply modify it to look for `next-auth.session-token`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the Supabase Auth Helpers: https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/blob/main/packages/nextjs/README.md

They provide a `withPageAuth` function for SSR: https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/blob/main/packages/nextjs/README.md#server-side-rendering-ssr---withpageauth

```
import { withPageAuth } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';

export default function Profile({ user }) {
  return <div>Hello {user.name}</div>;
}

export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuth({ redirectTo: '/signin' });
```

Comment: I tried switching over to this today and encountered several issues. I noticed the github page says it's beta. Are you using this successfully? If so, I might want to compare notes with you.